# ios: Accessing a navigation controller from app delegate

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, push-notification, pushviewcontroller, uiapplicationdelegate

I have an app that receives push notifications. In didReceiveRemoteNotifications, I would like to make the app show a particular view controller in the app's navigation controller (which happens to be the root view controller). What is the best way to make this happen? Can I get a reference to the navigation controller in the app delegate?

**EDIT:** Here is the code I'm trying to use right now. It appears to use the correct navigation controller, but it doesn't display the view controller at all, just a blank screen:

```
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
        EventDetailViewController *destCon = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"EventDetailViewController"];
        destCon.event=notifyEvent;
        UINavigationController *navController =(UINavigationController *) self.window.rootViewController;
        [navController pushViewController:destCon animated:YES];
```

Here is what I'm seeing:

[image]

Answer (score 53, accepted):

If your navigation controller is the root view controller of the window, then you can just use

```
(UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController
```

from the app delegate to access the one you created in the storyboard.

Comment: @JamesHarpe, Try logging self.window.rootViewController and see what it gives you.

Comment: how is this in swift?

Answer (score 11):

I use something like below it works for me, try to modify  for your usage

`Stoaryboard` is the name of your storyboard, when you recieve notification you can call your rootview `LoginViewController`

Make sure your viewcontroller in interface builder is set to  `yourControllerName` in below example it is `LoginView`

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{

        //replace and push rootview manually
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard" bundle:nil];
        LoginViewController *ivc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginView"];
        UINavigationController *navigationController=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:ivc];
        self.window.rootViewController =nil;
        self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

Comment: This creates a new navigation controller. I want to use the existing navigation controller that is currently on the screen. That way the user can press the back button and return to where they were.